# token _csrf in an url POST

Tags: vulnerability, csrf, token, url

I wanted to know if it was a bad thing to have a _csrf token stored in a url. I saw that in a POST request that allows me to upload a file, the _csrf token was displayed in the url. Is it sensitive to store this token in a url. Is there a way to exploit this vulnerability ?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transmitting sensitive information using an HTTP GET request should be avoided at all times, as it could be cached or end up in (proxy) server log files.

I do consider a session based anti-CSRF token as sensitive information. As the name suggests, the token is valid for the duration of the entire session.

As far as exploiting this, this might be rather hard, but it could be exploited when multiple vulnerabilities are present in the application.

Without any other type of vulnerabilities I consider the likelihood quite low.

Comment: thank you for your answer ! So, in any case, it's better to store it in an another place.

Comment: A header would be a solution or even a cookie with HTTPOnly and Secure attributes set.

Comment: ok thank you a lot for all this information !